# Conditional field in node type depending on user profile

Tags: users

I have a site with two user profiles (group/single). I have a node type repertoire with a field function which I only need for the profile single (mandatory field). Is there a way to hide this field when a user with profile group is adding a node? I don't want to make two different content types with only one little difference.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide a field from particular role via a contrib module, you can try

http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

or if you're comfortable in code, see

[hook_field_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7)

e.g:

```
function mymodule_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_of_interest' && $op == 'edit') {
    // TODO: some special access check for TRUE or FALSE in $access
    return $access;
  }
  return FALSE; // default deny
}
```